# Android App do not show in launcher

Tags: android, android-manifest

I'm a complete newbie to android programming and I was on an app which had the following source code:

```
    <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Guest"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:background="#FF697A"
        android:textSize="70sp"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Shivam Jha"
        android:background="#FF414D"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="40sp"/>

 <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Prabhakar"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:background="#FF414D"
        android:textSize="40sp"/>
    <ImageView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="280dp"
       android:src="@mipmap/patio"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:text="Google Office Front (USA)"
    android:background="#999999"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

When I buiilt this app, and moved the generated apk file to my samsung galaxy j2
with android v5.1.1 lolipop,and install it, it would successfully install ***but dont have an open option and don't even appears on the app drawer***.
Pleasse help me for the same..
Note:I'm sure that there isn't any problem of android version!!!

and here is my manifest file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.shivamjha.anonymous">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Post your Manifest.xml file.

Comment: Do you have any activity

Comment: You need to define activity in your Manifest.xml

Comment: Your Manifest file should define an Activity class with intent filter category as launcher in order to open up the application.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define activity in your AndroidManifest.xml with intent filter like this.

```
 <activity
        android:name=".activities.MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your Manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.activities">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
    android:name=".activities.MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

</application>
```